# MSDTC on server 'servername' is unavailable with linq to sql

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-web-api2, transactionscope

I am using Transactionscope with linqtosql. I have the following code:

```
public bool Save(int Id, List<Student> students, List<Subject> subjects)
 {
            var isDataSaved = false;
             using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
             {
                try
                {
                    // Save the students
                    SaveStudents(students);

                    // Save the subjects
                    SaveSubjects(subjects);

                    scope.Complete();

                    isDataSaved = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }

                return isDataSaved;
             }
 }
```

In both the methods I am using the two tables : Students, Subjects present in the same database. The datacontext object dependency is setup using the constructor as mentioned in the below class:

```
public class StudentsRepository:IStudentsRepository
{
   public StudentsRepository()
   {
     _dataContext = new SchoollDetailsDataContext(connectionString);
   }   
}
```

The same datacontext object is used in both the methods SaveStudents and SaveSubjects.

I am getting an exception : MSDTC on server 'servername' is unavailable.

As per my initial analysis this kind of error will occur  where a database operation will be in my local database and another will be in a remote database.

Can anyone help me to know is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: "The same datacontext object is used" I doubt that. There are two connections being opened here. This has nothing to do with local/remote. Post the full exception ToString. You have left out information.

Comment: What is that isDataSaved thing supposed to do? This method will always return true. Delete the variable and the catch.

Comment: The same _dataContext  is used firstime time in the method : SaveStudents and then carried over to SaveSubjects. The isDataSaved  variable value is used to keep track data being saved.

Comment: Post the exception ToString output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn the MSDTC service on.

Start-->Control Panel --> Administrative Tools --> services.
Find the service Distributed Transaction Coordinator and start it.
By default its startup property is set to Manual so its switched off.